# MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is not working

Tags: java, android, padding, ontouchlistener

I have two images which I am using as joysticks. `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is working fine and is padding the images in the correct direction. `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is suppose to return the image back to its default position but is not working. Here is my code for the listener:

```
//First joystick listener
    joystick1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
              Log.d("TouchTest", event.toString());
            //Gets the X and Y values of the users touch when the user is touching
            //the joystick move image
            X = event.getX();
            Y = event.getY();
            CY = cursor.getHeight()/2;
            CX = cursor.getWidth()/2;
            joystick1Move = true;

            int action = event.getAction();

            switch (action){
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                  Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch down");
                  //if the user has touched the image and moves finger right left
                    //up and down for the first joystick then move the joystick image
                    if(X>(joystick1width/2)&&X<(v.getWidth())){
                        //right
                        CX=CX+5;
                        joystick1.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                    }
                    if(X<(joystick1width/2)){
                        //left
                        CX=CX-5;
                        joystick1.setPadding(-20, 0, 0, 0);
                    }
                    if(Y>(joystick1height/2)&&Y<(v.getHeight())){
                        //up
                        CY=CY+5;
                        joystick1.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 20);
                    }
                    if(Y<(joystick1height/2)){
                        //down
                        CY=CY-5;
                        joystick1.setPadding(0,0, 0, -20);
                    } 
                    break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch up");
                  joystick1.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                  break;
              default:
                  Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch up");
                  joystick1.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```